# How should date-based queries in Oracle be parameterised

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(
    "select j.vc_jo_no,
            j.dt_jo_date,
            p.vc_product_name 
     from mst_jobcard j,
          mst_prod p 
     where j.vc_product_code=p.vc_product_code 
     and   j.dt_jo_date=to_char("+tdate+","+"'"+dd-mm-yy+"'"+")
    ");
```

In my specified query it should display the records based on the date parameter that is being passed in the above query.
the vc_jo_no,dt_jo_date are taken from mst_jobcard table and vc_product_name is taken from mst_prod table.
i have joined the tables.
please help me in how to use the to_char function for date.
when i specify the format i.e dd-mm-yy in the to_char function it gives error.
please help..

Comment: Please format your code, make appropriate use of punctuation and capital letters, and tell us **what the error says**!

Comment: It might also help to know what `st` is.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to pass the date as a string Oracle needs it surrounded by single quotes. Also, the "dd-mm-yy" doesn't look right to me. Try this:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(
"select j.vc_jo_no,
        j.dt_jo_date,
        p.vc_product_name 
 from mst_jobcard j,
      mst_prod p 
 where j.vc_product_code=p.vc_product_code 
 and   j.dt_jo_date=to_char('"+tdate+"','dd-mm-yy')
");
```

That said, this method of passing parameters is effectively NOT passing the parameter - it will cause the database to parse a different query for every different date requested, which is likely to cause a scalability issue.

The better approach would be to bind the parameter, using whatever method is provided by ResultSet to bind a variable. You may find you can even bind a date variable natively without having to convert it to a string.

Comment: +1 especially for bind variables.  If this is .Net then I think the syntax is: to_char(?,'dd-mm-yy')

Answer (score 1):

So you're running:

```
executeQuery("select … where … j.dt_jo_date=to_char("+tdate+","+"'"+dd-mm-yy+"'"+")");
```

First thing, try put that string in a variable, output it and see if it's in the correct format.

Have you tried:

```
"… to_char("+tdate+",'dd-mm-yy'")
```

it seems you're doing unnecessary acrobatics with that string.

And finally, take a look at "[Oracle to_char usage](http://www.dba-oracle.com/f_to_char_sql.htm)" by Burleson Consulting. It was the first link off of [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+to_char). Some say Google's a good place to look first.

Comment: + 1 "Some say Google's a good place to look first." - yeah, just a pity its always b****Y Burleson who comes out on top!